# is write to the middle of mapped adress will grow the file? just like fseek does?

Tags: c, file, mmap

[image: sample illustration]

if I write data to the middle of the allocated address space, will the file size increase. just like `fseek` does ?

or it will write to the beginning of the file ?

Comment: I don't understand. `fseek()` does not increase anything, nor will writing to the middle of a file increase anything (unless it goes past the end).

Comment: yes, i want to mmap for a future file.
so current actual file size is `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane or do i need to grow the file first ?

Comment: `fseek()` may be to beyond the end of a file but that does not grow it. You need to write to it.

Comment: no, i mean will it create a sparse file?

Comment: Shouldn't this be somewhat OS specific?

Comment: You have to grow the file yourself. You can use `ftruncate` for that. After you have done that you need to remap the file with `mmap/mremap` The file will be sparse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. writeto mmap will not grow the file or create sparse file.
I have to allocate the file manually.